# Is there any way to get current date in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I want to use mobile date in phonegap is there any to way to get it.

Comment: Answer: yes.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use javascript

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0, so always add + 1

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd}
if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
```

Answer (score 2):

The javascript's Date object is the only option.